# не могу скачать библиотеку disnake

Tags: disnake

я работал с пайтоном и решил попробовать перейти на джава, не понравилось, я удалили джаву и когда продолжил писать бота на пайтон то у меня появились некоторые проблема а именно я не могу установить билиотеки для работы с ботами (discord/disnake) и другие мне пишет очень большую ошибку, вот ее конец
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects